# How to query element in array of arrays in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I'm learning MongoDB on my own. I have a collection with entries that look like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d0c13fbfdca455311248d6f"),
"borough" : "Brooklyn",
"grades" : 
    [ 
        { "date" : ISODate("2014-04-16T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 5 },
        { "date" : ISODate("2013-04-23T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "B", "score" : 2 },
        { "date" : ISODate("2012-04-24T00:00:00Z"), "grade" : "A", "score" : 5 }
    ],
"name" : "C & C Catering Service",
"restaurant_id" : "40357437"
}
```

And I want to find all restaurants in Brooklyn with at least one grades.grade of A.

I've figured out the first half of the puzzle:

```
db.restaurants.find({borough:{$eq:"Brooklyn"}})
```

But how do I query in the "grades" array for grade A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use dot (`.`) to access and query nested objects:

```
db.restaurants.find({'borough':{$eq:"Brooklyn"}, 'grades.grade': 'A'})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
db.restaurants.find({"borough" : "Brooklyn","grades.grade":"A"})
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.